# Exactly when do you put 'even' before the comparative words?

Tags: grammar, comparative

One of common mistake that non-natives say is something as below.
(B is a non-native here)

> A: How was the movie? (expecting a good response)
>
> B: It was better than I expected. (meaning it was even better than he thought)
>
> A: Oh... well... (disappointed and thinks B didn't expect the movie that much)

As such, some of Youtube English classes mentioned that if you say like B did, where something is just better, not even better, than the other thing, then automatically the other thing feels not much at all.

So, I thought until now that if something is great already, and if you like to emphasize the other thing is greater than that, you should always use 'even' before the comparative word. Like "The cake tastes great, and the liquor is even greater", not "liquor is greater".

But I saw today, in my grammar book, this sentence below.

> I am pretty tall, but my dad is taller.

And here I'm confused. Why didn't they say "my dad is even taller"? Is it because of the word 'but' here? What's the golden rule of putting 'even' before the comparative words at all?

Comment: "Even" is usually used for emphasis. I, as a native speaker, never really think much about whether or not I should use it to be honest. I find it hard to make some rules on when you should use "even" besides it being for emphasis. Much of language is kind like that, just "feel", I think.

Comment: You are right that "better than I expected" usually implies "...but not all that great", while "even better than I expected" implies that your good expectations were exceeded. There isn't a 'golden rule', though. "...my dad is even taller" would be perfectly OK.